# How to send instance of custom struct with QSignalMapper?

Tags: c++, qt, struct, signals-slots

I have a custom struct of which instances of it are associated with **QAction** instances. I would like a slot to be executed with the corresponding instance of my struct when the action executes.

I managed to get this working using **QSignalMapper** by sub-classing **QObject** to encapsulate an instance of my struct. However, all of the values of my struct are incorrect when they arrive in the slot - they seem to be uninitialised.

If I send a primitive type such as an **int** in place of the struct, or even something like a **QAction**, everything works OK.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? If so, what am I missing?

Thanks,
Alan

**Edit: Added code sample**

The following is how I am wiring up the QSignalMapper. Note: STRUCT_WRAPPER derives from QObject.

```
/* Connect signal mapper to selected slot */
connect(signalMapper, SIGNAL(mapped(QObject *)), this, 
    SLOT(on_selected(QObject *)));

/* For all structures */
for(x = 0; x < structureCount; x++)
{
    /* Create action */
    QAction * action = ui.menu->addAction("Name");

    /* Get current structure */
    MY_STRUCT myStruct = structList[x];

    /* Create wrapper */
    STRUCT_WRAPPER * structWrapper = new STRUCT_WRAPPER(this, myStruct);

    /* Map struct to action */
    signalMapper->setMapping(action, structWrapper);
}
```

And here is the slot where I am getting uninitialised values:

```
void on_selected(QObject * object)
{
    /* Get structure wrapper */
    STRUCT_WRAPPER * structWrapper = (STRUCT_WRAPPER *)object;

    /* Get structure */
    MY_STRUCT myStruct = structWrapper->GetStruct();

    /* ID is always uninitialised */
    int id = myStruct.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the useful pointers.

In the end, I realised that the only information that I needed to be mapped was the index in the array of structs. By making the array global, I was able to access it from my slot using the index that was passed.

I didn't want to use the Q_DECLARE_METATYPE in this case because I'd rather not have QT dependencies on my API library. Otherwise, octal's suggestion would have worked too.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using QSignalMapper, which forces you to create a custom STRUCT_WRAPPER, try using the [QAction::setData](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qaction.html#setData) method, which accepts any QVariant

Also, make sure to register your struct to the Qt metatype system by using [Q_DECLARE_METATYPE](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmetatype.html#Q_DECLARE_METATYPE)

Then, just connect all your QAction to the same slot, and use http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender to retrieve the QAction that emitted the signal :

```
void MyWindow::on_selected() {
    QAction *action = qobject_cast<QAction *>(sender());
    Q_ASSERT(action);

    MY_STRUCT myStruct = action->data().value<MY_STRUCT>();
}
```

Also, avoid using C-style casts. If you're down casting QObjects, use qobject_cast instead (it relies on the MetaObject informations and doesn't need extra RTTI feature) :

```
STRUCT_WRAPPER * structWrapper = qobject_cast<STRUCT_WRAPPER *>(object;)
```

Comment: Thanks for that information. It looks like a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

why are you not just using a custom class to do the job? by deriving it from qobject and with some slots/signals it will do what you want.

i have no idea why your struct gets invalid values, so it would be good to get some code as example :)

soo long zaiborg

Comment: The struct is part of an API but I could possibly store its data in a custom class as you suggest. This just looked like the cleanest and simplest way to do it - apparently not. See my edited question for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

```
void on_selected(QObject * structWrapper)
{
    /* Get structure */
    MY_STRUCT myStruct = structWrapper->GetStruct();

    /* ID is always uninitialised */
    int id = myStruct.ID;
}
```

i think the problem is, that a QObject* has no idea what GetStruct() should do ... it should throw an error on compiling oO

maybe try

```
MY_STRUCT myStruct = <dynamic_cast>(STRUCT_WRAPPER*)->GetStruct();
```

Comment: Sorry, I am already doing something similar but forgot to include that in my code example. See edited question for clarification.

Comment: `MY_STRUCT myStruct = structList[x];`    you are connecting myStruct to the signal ... please try to use `MY_STRUCT* myStruct = &structList[x];`
so maybe you connect a invalid struct to your function

and i hope you clear it up, cause with the call of `new STRUCT_WRAPPER()` you may get some leaks as well